# Select the first child of type

Tags: css, css-selectors

In this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uLr6o99e/2/) how can I select the first child if I have other child?

```
<div class="root">
  <div>5</div>
  <div class="child">1</div> // i want this one

</div>
<div class="root">

  <div class="child">2</div> 

</div>
<div class="root">

  <div class="child">3</div> 

</div>
```

I try this css below but it doesn't work

```
.root:first-of-type  .child:first-of-type {
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: .root:first-child { color red; } but for the .child div inside each .root, there is only one child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be:

```
.root:first-child .child:last-child {
   color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uLr6o99e/7/

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
:not(.child) + .child {
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: How is it different from my answer?